# Razor Class Library, do not prioritize the Main App

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

If I have a page in the main app and in RazorLib, the main app page is always taken ... How do set this to be the priority by RazorLib?

Thus one can create a default "Theme" and with Razor simply "overwrite"

Or is that wrong? Do you have to insert the default theme in a RazorLib and if you want to change the theme to include the other?
The variant looks better to leave the original theme in the main app

Comment: You're definitely thinking the wrong way round here. The "default" theme should be in a Razor library and you override with cshtml in the host app.

Comment: To answer your question: there is no way. Anything explicitly defined in your main project will override anything coming from the RCL. That's by design, as the RCL should be your "default", and then your app can customize that as it sees fit, not the other way around.